# Ajax to load page and parse, can't use variables set within ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing

I'm using ajax to retrieve a set url and am getting a piece of information from the HTML of the site.

This much is working but when I try to use the variables that I set within the ajax they remain undefined. I know that ajax isn't the best way to do this, but I have a very short time to get this working and this method seems to be working the best out of everything else I've tried.

Heres the code I'm using:

```
 function getPrice() {
                alert("Getting Price");
                $.ajax( {
                    url: URL,
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype:"html",
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#holder').html($(result));
                        var textcontents = $('#holder').find('td').text();
                        var target = textcontents.split("\n");
                        Price = target[3];
                        price = Price;
                        alert(price);
                        return price;
                        }
                    });

                    db.transaction(updatePrice, successCB, errorCB);

            }
```

The price variable is attempted to be passed to the updatePrice function, but this error with the message Sql error Undefined, Undefined, as it doesn't appear to be passing the variables across. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var price; //this will be available anywhere within this scope

    function getPrice() {
        alert("Getting Price");
        $.ajax( {
            url: URL,
            type: "GET",
            datatype:"html",
            success: function(result) {
                $('#holder').html($(result));
                var textcontents = $('#holder').find('td').text();
                var target = textcontents.split("\n");
                price = target[3]; // lets set the price variable here
                alert(price);
                }
            });

            db.transaction(updatePrice, successCB, errorCB);
    }
    // rest of your application code goes here
}());
```

Now make sure that you are passing the `price` variable to the `updatePrice` function.